# Reading Excel using POI in java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have an excel file which has a couple of String datatype columns, one numeric column and one date column. Am using Apache POI to read the file.
Below is how am handling the datatypes

```
Cell cell = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(j);

                if(cell!=null){
                    switch(cell.getCellType()){
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING: 
                        cellValue = cell.getStringCellValue();
                        break;
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
                        Date cellDate = cell.getDateCellValue();
                        cellValue = df.format(cellDate);
                        break;                          
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
                        break;
                    default :
                    }                       
                }
```

This works fine with String and date datatypes. But for numeric, it's converting the value to a date. I know it's because the handling has issues. Can you please advise on how to accommodate handling of both numeric and date datatypes?

Thanks,
Sam.

Comment: Why not just use [DataFormatter](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html) to turn the Cell into a String, and have it handle the complexity for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know what data types belong to each column, you don't even have to check cell type every time:

```
switch (columnIndex) {
    case 0:
    case 1:
    case 2: { 
       cellValue = cell.getStringCellValue();
       break; 
    }
    case 3: {
       Date cellDate = cell.getDateCellValue();
       // ...
       break;
    } 
    case 4: {
       cellValue = cell.getNumericCellValue();
       break;
    }    
}
```

If your column can contain both dates and numbers, you can try this

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DateUtil;

case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
   if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
      // your code for date handling
   } else {
      cellValue = cell.getNumericCellValue();
   }
```

Comment: Thanks Adam !! Worked like a charm :)